# In ArrayList, how to remove subdirecyory if its parent is already present in the list?

Tags: java, arraylist

I've an `ArrayList<String>` containing paths of directiories, like:

```
/home, /usr...
```

I want to write a code that will remove all the paths from the list if the list already contains parent direcotry of that element.
For e.g:
If the list contains:

```
/home
/home/games
```

then, /home/games should get removed as its parent /home is already in the list. 
Below is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedList.size(); i++) {
            File f = new File(checkedList.get(i));
            if(checkedList.contains(f.getParent()));
            checkedList.remove(checkedList.get(i));
}
```

Above `checkedList` is a `String arrayList`.

**The problem comes when the list contains**:

```
/home
/home/games/minesweeper
```

Now the minesweeper folder will not get removed as its parent games is not in the list. How to remove these kinds of elements too?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possible solution would be using `String.startsWith(String)`.

---

But of course you could take advantage of parent functionality of `File` class in order to handle the relative directories and other particularities. Follows a draft of the solution:

```
List<String> listOfDirectories = new ArrayList<String>();
listOfDirectories.add("/home/user/tmp/test");
listOfDirectories.add("/home/user");
listOfDirectories.add("/tmp");
listOfDirectories.add("/etc/test");
listOfDirectories.add("/etc/another");

List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfDirectories.size(); i++) {
    File current = new File(listOfDirectories.get(i));
    File parent = current;
    while ((parent = parent.getParentFile()) != null) {
        if (listOfDirectories.contains(parent.getAbsolutePath())) {
            current = parent;
        }
    }
    String absolutePath = current.getAbsolutePath();
    if (!result.contains(absolutePath)) {
        result.add(absolutePath);
    }
}

System.out.println(result);
```

This would print:

```
[/home/user, /tmp, /etc/test, /etc/another]
```

Comment: How would you catch cases like `..\home`

Comment: what if the list contains "/home/games" before "/home"?

Comment: the sample posted covers both situation

Comment: I tried your code and in isolation it is working fine, but when I integrate it in my code, it is creating a weird problem @ [Psted Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11473642/android-listview-entry-is-made-when-checkbox-checked-but-entry-not-removing)

Answer (score 0):

You can substract the root from your string and add it to a hashset.

For example:

if you have /home/games you can substract "home" from the string using string substraction or a regular expression or whateever you want.

before you add "home" to the hashset you must check if it's already added:

```
     if (hashset.Contains("home"))
             {
                //then it s already added
              }

    else

     {
           hashhset.add("home");
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check every parent of each list item in turn.

I will assume that your list contains normalized absolute path `File` objects:

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedList.size(); i++) {
    File curItem = checkedList.get(i);
    for (
        File curParent = curItem.getParent( );
        curParent != null;
        curParent = curParent.getParent( )
    )
    {
        if(checkedList.contains( curParent ) )
        {
            checkedList.remove( curItem );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, I would rewrite it with `ListIterator`

```
for (ListIterator iter = checkedList.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); )
{
    File curItem = iter.next();
    for (
        File curParent = curItem.getParent( );
        curParent != null;
        curParent = curParent.getParent( )
    )
    {
        if(checkedList.contains( curParent ) )
        {
            iter.remove( );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

would doing the opposite work? if the parent is NOT found in your ArrayList, add the value to a final output ArrayList?

```
for (int i = 0; i < checkedList.size(); i++) {
            File f = new File(checkedList.get(i));
            if(!checkedList.contains(f.getParent()));
            yourOutputList.Add(checkedList.get(i));
}
```